# How can I predict test image is not cat or dog if I provide other image from Keras?

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I use multiple category of images such as bird/cat/dog/lion.

after epoch = 40

my **testData.py** is :

```python
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import model_from_json
import cv2, numpy as np


np.set_printoptions(precision=4, linewidth=100) 

# -------------Load Trained Model------------------------------

model = load_model('onlyModel.h5')
print('Loaded model from disk')

# -------------Load and Pre process Test img ----------------
img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('a.jpg'), (150, 150))
img = np.reshape(img,[1,150,150,3])
array = np.asarray(img, dtype='int32')
array = array / 255

# --------------------Predictions------------------------------
predict = model.predict(array)
classes = model.predict_classes(array)            

print('Prediction is = ', predict)
print('predict_class is = ',classes )
# ------------------Result--------------------------------------
if classes  == 0:
    print ('It is a Bird')
elif classes  == 1:
    print ('It is Cat')
elif classes  == 2:
    print ('It is Dog')
elif classes  == 3:
    print ('It is Lion')    
else:
    print ('N/A')   

# ------------------------------------------------
```

Correctly Gives output when I provide Dog image :

[image]

But this doesn't predict lion image ??

Please correct my code errors if any. I am new to this. Also suggest best possible approach than this.

Comment: This is not a programming question, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/ for general Machine Learning questions.

Comment: Are you still using binary cross entropy? You should switch to categorical cross entropy, with a third class: 'other' and create a 3-dim target vector that reflects all three categories.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by 'all I get is only 0 & 1' ? Using cross entropy should give a continous spectrum of outputs which can be interpreted as something like normalized probabilities for each class. For more info see paragraph about the [softmax classifier](http://cs231n.github.io/linear-classify/). Can you please add the part of your code, where you define your model and start the training.

Comment: Do you use the same number of images for each class?

Comment: Do you use the same number of images for each class?  -- Yes

Comment: You should switch to categorical cross entropy -- Yes I switched .. See updated code now

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that you trained your model with only cat and dog which are categorical variables and quite possible you used their numerical equivalent. You should update your dataset and model to include things that are neither cat nor dog.

Comment: I see. Please check my Code. I changed from Binary_crossentropy to Categorical_crossentropy. Added Lion images in separate train and validation folder but fro any image  it predicts 0 class but not other ??

Answer (score 1):

It seems you only do feature scaling when you train the model. `rescale=1./ 255,` but you didn't do the same thing when you make the model to recognize a lion image. the input would be much larger `[0,255]`, you should add these code after reshape the image:

```
    array = np.asarray(image, dtype='int32')
    array = array / 255
```

If it doesn't work, you may consider if your model is overconfident, see [Overfitting in classifiers leads to overconfident predictions](https://www.coursera.org/learn/ml-classification/lecture/FIYUC/overfitting-in-classifiers-leads-to-overconfident-predictions), try to add regularization term to you model.

Wish it helps.

Comment: You need to put the `array` instead of the img to the predict function. Make sure all elements of the input are less than +1. BTW, what's the size of your train set?

Comment: Thanks I updated code. I don't understand this "Make sure all elements of the input are less than +1." ? Train dataset contains 46 images in each category [bar,cat,dog,Lion] . I am doubting this might be labeling issue or less dataset . Now testData.py predicts cat and dog correctly but for rest two categories it shows dog as prediction class.

Comment: It's mean after feature scaling (`array = array / 255`), all the elements would be ranged in `[0,1]`. Does it work for you?

Comment: I see your result, the `0.5534` means the model has 0.5534 confidence that the input image is a dog. 0.5534 is not a high number, that is to say, the model doesn't sure about the image. So, I think your model is OK. `predict_class = [0]`, where 0 is the index of your classes, the dog is 0 and cat is 1, the lion is 2 and so on.

Comment: all the elements would be ranged in [0,1]. Does it work for you? -- Yes It worked. but when I feed lion test image its not showing predict_class = [2] instead it shows [0]

Comment: You won't get a 100% accuracy model, the model can make mistakes sometimes, you need to feed more images of a lion to train the model to improve the accuracy so that the model would make a proper prediction.

Comment: Thanks Craig. Please see update answer below of how I am generating train dataset. Also Please check PLT graph updated in main answer !